# Limit of a defined positive symmetry

Tags: matrices

Let $A:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S_n^{++}(\mathbb{R})$ continuous with a continuous derivative.

**We suppose that $\forall t\in\mathbb{R},\mathrm{tr}(A'(t))\le-\mathrm{tr}(A(t))$. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}A(t)=0$**

---

Notations : $S_n^{++}(\mathbb{R})$ : Symmetric linear function $f$ such that $\forall x,  \left<f(x)\mid x\right> > 0$

---

I am looking for at least a good enough hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** it is sufficient to show that $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} \lim_{t \to \infty} \tr(A(t)) = 0$, noting that $\tr(A(t)) \geq 0$ by positivity.

We note that 
$$
f(t) = e^t(\tr(A(t)))
$$
is non-increasing.  It follows that $\tr(A(t)) \leq \tr(A(0))e^{-t}$.

Comment: The last part does not imply that the limit is zero. But $t\mapsto\mathrm e^t\cdot\mathrm{tr}(A(t))$ is nonincreasing...

Comment: @Did How did you get that result ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon differentiate with the product rule.

Comment: Differentiating (what else?).